# Spark SQL returns all nulls, while direct Hive works and direct Parquet through Spark works

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet

I'm having a weird problem with Spark SQL on an external table defined in Hive with

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ... STORED AS PARQUET... LOCATION 'hdfs://path/TABLENAME'`

If I refer to the table in Spark with `spark.table("tablename")` or `spark.sql("select column from tablename")` I get the right row count but every value is null.

When I query the table through Beeline, I get the right values.

Additionally, if I query the Parquet directly in Spark with `spark.read.parquet("hdfs://path/TABLENAME")` I also get the right answer.

To make it even stranger - if I create another external table with a similar `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE...` statement against the same Parquet in HDFS, *Spark SQL works*.

Where do I look next?

Comment: try adding the schema in the select statement.

Comment: clarified that it doesn't matter if I use `select *` or `select column`

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue running hive SQL from ab initio now. My SQL did not have aliases for each field. When I added the alias it worked.